# How can i post value from Ajax to Controller (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Post data includes that name and surname. These datas are posted (show request console) but firebug give me 404 error about "POST localhost/index.php/getdata/ 404 Not Found"

```
function gonder(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/index.php/getdata/',
        data:$('#form1').serialize(),
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#yaz').html(msg);
            $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
}

public function getdata()
    {
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        if ( ! isset($_POST['data']))
        {
            $data = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
        }
        $this->load->view("getdata_view");
        $data = $this->input->post('data');
        var_dump($data);
    }
```

Comment: Have you fixed your routing for /index.php/getdata/ already? See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Ajax url, perhaps you want to include base_url() so that it is going to the right location regardlass of which page you are. Secondly, as @meavo pointed out, set the routing properly. Right now, we can't tell anything as your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your path..is '/index.php/getdata/'  the right path?

It should be /index.php/yourcontrollername/yourmethodname(getdata in your case).

Comment: index.ph
<?php
Class Index extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("index_view");
    }
    
    public function getdata()
    {
        
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        if ( ! isset($_POST['data']))
        {
            $data = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
        }
        $this->load->view("getdata_view");
        $data = $this->input->post('data');
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
?>

Comment: localhost/hakan/index.php/index/getdata that's right thanks;)